# VPN without public IP

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, network-share, port-forwarding

For tests I need to tunel communication from my MachineA to second place (internet traffic needs to exit from there). On both sides there is no public IP.

I was thinking about configuring OpenVPN server in second place, renting some VPS with public IP, SSH local forward OpenVPN to VPS.
Will that allow me to simply connect to this port on VPS and have working tunel?

But additional problem is, that on MachineA I cannot install anything. Is possible using MachineB (on the same place) to connect to the OpenVPN and share connection for MachineA?

Comment: If you can't install any software on one of the machines, how are you going to install the OpenVPN client?

Comment: ALso, how you think you will establish a connection between two machines who have no means of addressing each other AT ALL?

Comment: And this is reason I'm asking. There is no option on 2nd site to have public IP, but for tests I need to have my requests go out of there.

Comment: O.K., in a business environment we'd have an ablility to request public IP, software installation, etc. to get the task done. So you have to that. Without public IP at least at one side and the probability to install and configure software your problem doesn't have a solution. I mean, reading only the title one should decide "that's impossible".

Comment: If I would have public IP on my side, is there an option to do that? I can install stuff on MachineB as well as on second place machine.